# pygame display's a black screen even though indentation is correct

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am learning pygame but I am not sure the reason why it gives me only a black screen. I have confirmed that indentation is correct. My code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True

while running:
    screen.fill((255,255,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    pygame.display.update()
```

I don't see anything wrong with this program and now I am confused.

Comment: Try `pygame.display.flip()`

Comment: There is no change in behaviour with `pygame.display.flip()` too. It still shows black screen.

Comment: Just installed `pygame==2.0.0.dev6` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the icon and it worked for me (I think that you need to use .ico file instead of .png)

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')

running = True

while running:
    screen.fill((255,255,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.update()
```